# Attaching two or more jQuery files to a theme

Tags: theming, 8

I was trying to add some jQuery files to a theme (to do some simple css logics). I could add one jQuery file by defining as follows

In the custom theme folder I edited themes.libraries.yml and added the following

```
global-scripts:
  js:
    js/jqueryfile1.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

and then I wrote my jquery code within inside custom_theme_folder/js/jqueryfile1.js as

```
(function ($){
Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //code goes here

            });
        });
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Everything was fine till now. But when I'm trying to add my next file(jqueryfile2.js) only the the latest (jqueryfile2.js) is taking in action. I can see the previous file is also called in the DOM while checking the source but the code is not executing. After adding my second jQuery my libraries.yml will look like

```
global-scripts:
  js:
    js/jqueryfile1.js: {}
    js/jqueryfile2.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

At this point jqueryfile2.js is only taking in action not the first file. And there will be both my jquery files within inside the js folder and is called to the document.

Comment: What jqueryfile2.js file consist of same DOM events or other?

Comment: I'd guess you have used the Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior.attach in both files.

Answer (score 1):

By default, multiple local files will be aggregated where possible. To disable this for a file, set its 'preprocess' flag to false.

```
mymodule:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/custom.js: {preprocess: false}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the example

```
maintenance-page:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/mobile.install.js: {}

install-page:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/mobile.install.js: {}


drupal.nav-tabs:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/nav-tabs.js: {}
```

Taken from Seven theme **seven.libraries.yml** file.

Comment: Thats a way to look but i was facing problem when adding two or more files in the global section. Or as per your example what we do if we want to add two files in the maintenance-page

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to add js file to your custom module, mymodule.libraries.yml.

```
mymodule:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui
```